# PyQGIS - setting color of existing categorised symbol (from .qml) crashes QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qml

I have several layers in a project which have existing style files applied.
I want to modify the symbol color attributes using python.
The symbols are QgsFillSymbol objects.

This seems to work fine for layers with a single symbol, using the QgsSingleSymbolRenderer via the code below:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()  #QgsSingleSymbolRenderer    
symbol = renderer.symbol()
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,128,0))
layer.triggerRepaint()      
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

However, QGIS crashes when I attempt to do this for categorised symbols via the QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer, using the code below:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()    #QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer
symbol = renderer.categories()[0].symbol()  # select first category
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,128,0))  # --CRASHES HERE--
```

the symbol is a valid qgis._core.QgsFillSymbol object, and `renderer.categories()` returns the expected layer categories:

```
[<qgis._core.QgsRendererCategory object at 0x000001E64BD148B0>, <qgis._core.QgsRendererCategory object at 0x000001E64BD14940>, <qgis._core.QgsRendererCategory object at 0x000001E64BD14820>, <qgis._core.QgsRendererCategory object at 0x000001E64BD14A60>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer` class has a method `updateCategorySymbol()`.

So you could create a new `QgsFillSymbol` object, set its color and pass it to the `updateCategorySymbol()` method along with your category index.

Try the code snippet below:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()    #QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer
symbol = QgsFillSymbol()
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,128,0))
renderer.updateCategorySymbol(0, symbol)
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Link to docs [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer.html#a8e36ae87d84ee8b1d2c0fa76eb3384eb).

Comment: Many thanks, that works perfectly.

Comment: @BrocSamson, you're welcome :)